# A word that means that something doesn't matter if not finished

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means something doesn't matter if not finished. Basically, unless you can finish this thing, it is not even worth starting.

Example: John thought about baking a cake, but figured that it was _______ because he didn't have the time to finish.

Comment: 'All-or-nothing'?

Comment: Unconsequential? Irrelevant?

Comment: Your example doesn't align very well with your question. Nothing about it indicates that John wouldn't finish the repainting, just that it would take a while, and in the interim, the house would look bad. You might want to consider providing a different example.

Comment: @RichardKayser Better?

Comment: I second irrelevant.  Perhaps also unimportant, academic, and [a] moot [point].  Think it's inconsequential rather than unconsequential though.

Comment: The *reason* might matter. Did John give up? Would someone else complete the job? Was it unimportant to John? Etc. Further context to the use of your word would be helpful.

Comment: The example still seems a bit odd. Would this work better? > John thought about watching a movie, but figured that it was __________ because the plane would land before he could finish it.

Comment: I'm trying to find a word that describes something that does not obtain any value at all until that task (or whatever) is finished. Something that might as well be a waste of time all the way to 99% completed. For that, I think my current example works a bit better, but I know it's still lacking and am open to suggestions that better illustrate my point.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a literal translation of the concept (actually, 'moot' is kind of a hard word to explain), but I'd use:

> John thought about baking a cake, but figured that it was moot because he
>   didn't have the time to finish.

Answer (score 1):

**Fruitless** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fruitless)

> *adjective* Producing no good results : not successful
>
> *"They made a fruitless attempt to find a solution."*
> *"It would be fruitless to continue."*